# Limit the amount of lines in a multi line asp.net textbox

Tags: asp.net, textbox

On my asp.net web page I have a large multi line textbox where I want the user to be able to only fill in a maximum of 5 lines of text. (If the user were to press enter while on the 5th line it would simply not let him.)

The code I have for the textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox textmode="multiline"
             runat="server"
             ID="TextBox1"
             name="TextBox1"
             style="OVERFLOW:hidden; height:165px; width:95%; resize:none;">

</asp:TextBox>
```

I have tried it with the Rows property and several JavaScript functions, with no success.

Is this possible with an asp.net textbox or is there any other type of textbox I could use in this case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with the asp:TextBox without some extra work.  FYI, the "Rows" and "Columns" properties are only a display metrics and won't restrict the number of characters or carriage returns. The MaxLength property is also well documented to be disabled when using "multiline" with an asp:Textbox.

***However***, you do have a few options shown below.  Note: typically input is validated by length because you don't want it to exceed the field size in the database tables. Hopefully these examples will help.

**1) Roll your own Javascript validator.**
(this example is limited to validating length, not carriage returns, but you could customize further.)

```
<asp:TextBox textmode="multiline"
             runat="server"
             ID="TextBox1"
             name="TextBox1"
             onkeypress="return EnforceFieldLengthMax(this,10)"
             style="OVERFLOW:hidden; height:165px; width:95%; resize:none;">
        </asp:TextBox>

<script language="javascript">   
        function EnforceFieldLengthMax(txt, maxLen)
        {
            if (txt.value.length > (maxLen - 1))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

**2) Regular Expression validator** 
(Unfortunately, this won't fire until the control loses focus, so I don't think this one is what you're looking for, but here is an example just in case)**

```
 <asp:TextBox textmode="multiline"
             runat="server"
             ID="TextBox2"
             name="TextBox2"
             style="OVERFLOW:hidden; height:165px; width:95%; resize:none;">
        </asp:TextBox>

<asp:Label AssociatedControlID="txtValidateMe"></asp:Label>


<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="TextBox2Validator" 
                                ControlToValidate="TextBox2" ErrorMessage="Entry can't exceed 20 characters"
                                ValidationExpression="^[\s\S]{0,20}$" runat="server" Display="Dynamic"  SetFocusOnError="true" />
```

**3) Use the HTML TextArea object which does enforce MaxLength**

```
<textarea maxlength="50"></textarea>
```